# What is more efficient that np.sum and numpy boolean operators?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, boolean-logic

I am having some trouble getting my code to run quickly.

After using a line by line profiler on my code, I have found that the following lines are where most of my inefficiencies come from:

```py
import numpy as np
import datetime

timestamps = np.array(timestamps)
mask = (minTime <= timestamps) & (timestamps <= maxTime)
count = np.sum(mask)
```

`timestamps` starts out as a list of datetimes, and `minTime` is a single datetime.

An example value for timestamps:

```
minTime = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26)

timestamps = [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26), 
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 30, 55),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 30, 55), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 30, 55),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 34, 26), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 34, 26),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 34, 26), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26)]
```

Is there a more efficient way to rewrite the code above?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: 'datetimes' and 'date time' are vague.  Show some actual code that create this array.  Also I don't see how lines like that fit in a 'iterations/loops/map/reduce/filter' context.

Comment: Please provide a sample input.

Comment: The iterations part wasn't necessary, so I removed it. I have added the sample inputs

Comment: you might (or might now) squeeze more efficiency out of an array of numpy datetime64 or pandas timestamp objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `numpy.datetime64` objects are pretty fast. About a 2x speed up from standard lib `datetime`. Pandas kind of flounders here. It does a little bit better than what you see below if you use the pandas Timestamps as an index on Series object and use the `.loc` accessor. But not that much better.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import numpy
import pandas


py_dts = numpy.array([
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26), 
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 30, 55),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 30, 55),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 30, 55),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 34, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 34, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 34, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26),
    datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26)
])

min_pydt = datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 27, 26)
max_pydt = datetime(2020, 5, 21, 2, 39, 26)

min_npdt = numpy.datetime64(min_pydt)
max_npdt = numpy.datetime64(max_pydt)

min_pddt = pandas.Timestamp(min_pydt)
max_pddt = pandas.Timestamp(max_pydt)

np_64s = numpy.array([numpy.datetime64(d) for d in py_dts])
pd_tss = pandas.Series([pandas.Timestamp(d) for d in py_dts])


def counter(timestamps, mindt, maxdt):    
    return ((mindt <= timestamps) & (timestamps <= maxdt)).sum()
```

In the a Jupyter notebook I did:

```
%%timeit
counter(py_dts, min_pydt, max_pydt)
```

> 17.4 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
counter(np_64s, min_npdt, max_npdt)
```

> 7.42 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
counter(pd_tss, min_pddt, max_pddt)
```

> 531 µs ± 2.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Does this mean that it is less expensive to cast my date time values from standard datetime to np.datetime64 then do my operations? Will the casting add an additional operation per loop that I should avoid?

Comment: @EmaadShamsi I did all of the casting ahead of time. I didn't time the casting, as you see here. The total runtime including the casting will vary based on the amount of data you have and should be evaluated on a case-by-case basis

Comment: I understand, its still extremely useful information. I just checked and I was actually using pandas timestamps not date times. How would I cast this to np.datetime64 in my DataFrame? Also, do you know of a way to count if both statements are true that is more efficient that using the numpy library?

Comment: @EmaadShamsi did you try `numpy.datetime64(timestamp)`?